# Webpage form not hitting POST when submitting in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, google-chrome, iis

Recently a few days ago I was working on a problem and when I was hitting submit on a form in Google Chrome, the back-end code doesn't get hit and Chrome continues trying to load the page.

[image: a]

The form isn't anything special

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
{
    if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("error")</div>
    }

    <div class="field-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Email, new { required = "required" })
    </div>

    <div class="field-group field-password">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(i => i.Password, new { required = "required" })
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-eye" id="passwordToggle"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="button-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </div>
}
```

But it is happening on both my desktop and my laptop, but it is fine when I try FireFox. It is trying to load the page because it has the spinner in Chrome but when I place a breakpoint right at the start of the method, it is never hit.

Added part of login method as requested

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        //List<string> whiteListedEmailAddresses = new List<string>();

        //if (!whiteListedEmailAddresses.Contains(model.Email))
        //    ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Invalid Username and or Password");

        var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email == model.Email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Incorrect email address and/or password. If you are a customer, please switch to the customer site.");
        }
```

Comment: can you show the beginning of the login method?

Comment: Added the first bit of the login method.

Comment: +1 I'm experiencing the exact same as you. Also not hitting my controller action when submitting. The browser tab "spins" but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue in Chrome as well. The cause for me: I was disabling the submit button after it was being clicked.

For Chrome, but not other browsers, the click handler seems to fire before the submit handler. For that reason, I never got to back to the controller.

The solution for me was to not disable the submit button at all after the user clicked it.

Is it possible your submit button is somehow getting disabled immediately after you click it?